# DataSearch and RR Redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, reactivesearch

I'm using ReactiveSearch search components to build a nice UI for my search app. I'm using the prop onQueryChange to invoke a function that uses  to route to the search results page after user has submitted a search query.

How can I use React Router v4's  to redirect to search results page after user has submitted query with the DataSearch component?

So far I have

```
<DataSearch
  ..
  onQueryChange={
    (prevQuery, nextQuery) => {
      console.log("prev query: ", prevQuery);
      console.log("next query: ", nextQuery);
      { nextQuery !== '' &&  
      <Redirect to="/results"/>,
       }
      }
    }
```

I looked [here](https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivesearch/issues/399) and tried to change it for my use case. However, its not working.

**UDPATE:**

In regards to my comment below. I remembered that I had asked a similar question before, so I went to my profile to see if I could find it and I did. I combined that info with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51910986/reactivesearch-search-from-any-route) and I believe I was able to come up with the solution:

```
if (redirect) {
  return <Redirect to={{
     pathname: '/search',
     state: { pathname: this.state.redirect }
    }}/>
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For redirection it would be better to use `onValueSelected` ([docs](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/search-components/datasearch.html#extending)) since query would change everytime you type something in the searchbox (in order to fetch the suggestions).

In order to handle redirection declaratively with React router 4, you would update the `state` of your parent component when a value is selected and conditionally render the `Redirect` component from react router. For example,

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/r5k3rzylo4)

```
class Main extends Component {
  state = {
    redirect: false
  };

  render() {
    const { redirect } = this.state;
    if (redirect) {
      // when this renders it would redirect to the specified route
      return <Redirect to="/search" />;
    }
    return (
      <ReactiveBase
        ...
      >
          <DataSearch
            ...
            onValueSelected={(value, cause, source) => {
              // just setting the redirect state to true for redirection
              this.setState({
                redirect: true
              });
            }}
          />
      </ReactiveBase>
    );
  }
}
```

An alternate way would be to use `withRouter` higher order component from React Router but the above method would also work.

Comment: thanks. This works great if say I'm on '/' going to '/search'.  It doesn't work so great if I'm using it in the DataSearch component in the global Header. I'm guessing it would take some tweaking of the if statement. I've tried if (pathname !== '/search') {... but that just locks the page on '/search'. How could I tweak the if statement to account for redirecting to /search from any route

Comment: got carried away there. The app compiles and renders but that actual if statement for the global DataSearch component doesn't redirect to '/search' from any page. You gave me this onValueSelected={(val) => Router.push(`?q=${val}`)}  // using nextjs router here for example from a similar question. How could I tweak that for React Router?

Comment: Next router has a bit different API. Here you can use the `withRouter` higher order component to push directly to history from react router. [Here's](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/) a blog post I found, might be useful :)